# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'firebase_auth'. > Could not find the firebase_core FlutterFire plugin

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, firebase-authentication, sdk

Everything was working smoothly. I tried to add **google_mobile_ads** package to pubspec.yaml, after adding this package, whenever I run the app it said minSdk version should not be less than 19.

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:google_mobile_ads] D:\Academic\My Work\Software Projects\My Mates\my_mates\build\google_mobile_ads\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
  or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
  or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

So I updated the minSdkVersion in android/app/build.gradle from 16 to 19. Now whenever I run the code it says

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'firebase_auth'.
Could not find the firebase_core FlutterFire plugin, have you added it as a dependency in your pubspec?
```

Though I've updated **firebase_auth(^3.0.1)** & **firebase_core(^1.4.0)** to the latest version but nothing worked.

Its weird to see many related questions but without solution. Anyone who encountered the same problem please share how to overcome it and rebuild the app successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter clean` in your terminal.

After that, run `flutter packages get` again to download the latest packages in your application.